# Crash when injecting a pre-obtained object

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependency-injection, typhoon

I want to use an object that I got from another module. I cannot figure out how to use

> #Instructing Typhoon to Inject a Pre-obtained Instance

from the [doc](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Activating-Assemblies)

I am trying to do this so:

```
self.someAssembly = [[SomeAssembly new] activated];
[self.someAssembly inject:someObject];
SomeModule *module = [self.someAssembly getModule];
```

If I try to inject it by type in some definition I get crash with message:

> No components defined which satisify type: 'SomeObject'

So how can I use this very `someObject` in my definitions from `SomeAssembly`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because injecting an object that was built outside of Typhoon does not register it with the assembly.

Is it possible you can register a definition?